# Using UIImages for multiple resolutions that are not in the main app bundle

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiimage

in my app I have a number of images stored in a `NSMutableDictionary`, this number of images will change dynamically. I know that if I am using images included in the main app bundle I can include images for various resolutions i.e `image.png` `image@2x.png` and `image@3x.png`, I can then use `[UIImage imageNamed: "image.png"]` and it will automatically select the correct one for the screen resolution. What about if these images aren't in the main app bundle? In my NSMutableDictionary do I need to include three separate images for each resolution and then somehow select it manually using logic to detect the screen size? I'd really appreciate any advice on this! Thanks!